# Why are some CKEditor configurations working and not others?

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using *CKEditor 4* in Drupal 7 using the *CKEditor* module. I have the following configuration at `/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/[profile]`:

```
config.stylesCombo_stylesSet = 'my_styles:/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor-styles.js';
config.stylesSet = 'my_styles:/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor-styles.js';
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false; // Prevent filler nodes
config.language_list = [ "en:English", "es:Spanish", "zh:Chinese", "ar:Arabic:rtl", "fil:Filipino", "fr:French", "ja:Japanese", "ko:Korean", "ru:Russian", "th:Thai", "vi:Vietnamese" ];
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
  ev.editor.on('paste', function(evt) { 
    evt.data.dataValue = evt.data.dataValue.replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ');
     evt.data.dataValue = evt.data.dataValue.replace(/<p> *<\/p>/g,'');
    console.log(evt.data.dataValue);
  }, null, null, 9);
});
```

The *fillEmptyBlocks* configuration is working. Extra returns are removed on save and on paste from Word.

However, the *dropdown* for the language icon only contains the *CKEditor* default of Arabic, French, and Spanish, not the list of 11 languages that I've supplied.

And pasting *A[tab]B[tab]C[tab]D[tab]E* from Word, which converts the tabs to a series of non-breaking spaces, retains the non-breaking spaces.

Any ideas why these configurations are being overlooked and how to make them work?

Comment: Please make your title more specific so that your post attracts people who know the CKEditor module.

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in my code. The config statments needed to be surrounded by:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
```

and

```
}
```

which I discovered by looking at ckeditor.config.js in the CKEditor module.